# Using ObjectStreams to send Lists over sockets

Tags: java, file, sockets, object, inputstream

I need to transfer a List between nodes and replace the existing one with the new one in the new node to achieve this, I'm using Sockets from Java.

I somehow have managed to transfer the data but only when I terminate the process. I need it to continue running, the process but at the same time transfer, the data in case any other new node joins the List.
How can I achieve this? I will have to introduce Threads in the Download along the road.

I got it working with files but now I need to change it to Sync lists, just having this is enough?

```
private static List<CloudByte> cloudByteList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

This is my current code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import static FileData.getCloudByteList;
import static FileData.getFile;

public class FileData {

    private static File file;
    private static String fileName;
    private static List<CloudByte> cloudByteList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    public FileData(String fileName) throws IOException {
        if (fileName == null) {
            this.fileName = "data2.bin";
            this.file = new File(this.fileName);
            Download.downloadFile();
        } else {
            this.file = new File(fileName);
            this.fileName = fileName;
            fillingList();
        }
    }

    public void fillingList() throws IOException {
        byte[] fileContents = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        for (int i = 0; i < fileContents.length - 1; i++) {
            cloudByteList.add(new CloudByte(fileContents[i]));
        }
    }

    public static List<CloudByte> getCloudByteList() {
        return cloudByteList;
    }

    public static File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public static void setFile(File file) {
        FileData.file = file;
    }

    /*--------------------------Download--------------------------*/

}

class Download extends Thread {
    static ConnectingDirectory connectingDirectory;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            downloadFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void downloadFile() throws IOException {

        var nodes = ConnectingDirectory.getNodes();

        Socket socket = null;

        if (getFile().exists()) {
            System.out.println("File: " + getFile() + " exists.");
            new Upload().uploadFile();
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FileData.getFile());
        //ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);


        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (!(nodes.get(i).getHostPort() == ConnectingDirectory.getHostIP())) {
                System.out.println("test33123");

                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(nodes.get(i).getHostPort());
                System.out.println(serverSocket);
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("now socket");
                System.out.println(socket);
                //socket = new Socket(nodes.get(i).getName(), nodes.get(i).getHostPort());
                //System.out.println(socket);
                int bytes = 0;
                DataInputStream ois = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                long size = ois.readLong();
                System.out.println(size);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[100 * 10000];
                while (size > 0 && (bytes = ois.read(buffer, 0, (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
                    System.out.println("test3333");
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    size -= bytes;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

/*--------------------------Upload--------------------------*/

class Upload {

    public void uploadFile() throws IOException {
        int bytes = 0;
        var nodes = ConnectingDirectory.getNodes();

        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("data.bin");
        DataInputStream ois = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);

        if (!getFile().exists()) {
            System.out.println("File doesn't exist." + "\nDownloading the file!");
            new Download().downloadFile();
        }
        System.out.println("hello");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size() - 1; i++) {
            System.out.println("hello2");
            Socket socket = new Socket(nodes.get(i).getName(), nodes.get(i).getHostPort());
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeLong(new File("data.bin").length());
            byte[] buffer = new byte[100 * 10000];
            while ((bytes = ois.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                dos.flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm using DataInput because if I try to use the ObjectInputStream, I get a Corrupted Header Exception. I have more classes to add to this. My goal is as I said, to transfer the data inside the "data.bin" to a "data2.bin" file. I'm able to create it and delete it but at the same time, no Data is being written/sent to it.
How can I fix the CorruptedHeaderException and get it to send the content?
All help is appreciated.

StorageNode Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import static FileData.*;

public class StorageNode extends Thread {

private static int serverPort = 8080;
private static int clientPort = 8082;
private static String fileName = null;
private static String addressName = "localhost";


private static ConnectingDirectory connectingDirectory;
private static FileData fileData;
static ErrorInjection errorInjection;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

   /* if (args.length > 3) {
        addressName = args[0];
        serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        clientPort = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        fileData = new FileData(args[3]);
    } else {
        fileName = null;
        fileData = new FileData(fileName);
    }*/
    connectingDirectory = new ConnectingDirectory(addressName, clientPort, serverPort);
    fileData = new FileData(fileName);
    errorInjection = new ErrorInjection();
    errorInjection.start();
    if(fileData.getFile().exists()){
        new Upload().uploadFile();
    }else {
        new Download().downloadFile();
    }
}
```

ConnectingDirectory Class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConnectingDirectory {

    private String hostName;
    private static int hostIP;
    private int directoryIP;
    private InetAddress address;
    private InputStream in;
    private OutputStream out;
    private static List<Nodes> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> nodess = new ArrayList<>();
    private Socket socket;
    private String sign = "INSC ";


    public ConnectingDirectory(String hostName, int hostIP, int directoryIP) throws IOException {
        this.hostName = hostName;
        this.hostIP = hostIP;
        this.directoryIP = directoryIP;
        this.address = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);
        this.socket = new Socket(address, directoryIP);
        signUp();
        askConnectedNodes();
    }

    public void signUp() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("You are connecting to the following address: " + hostIP + "\n");
        System.out.println("The port you are connected to: " + socket.getPort() + "\n");
        in = socket.getInputStream();
        out = socket.getOutputStream();
        out.write(generateSignUp(address, hostIP).getBytes());
        out.flush();
    }

    public String generateSignUp(InetAddress address, int hostIP) {
        String signUpString = sign + address + " " + hostIP + "\n";
        return signUpString;
    }

    public void askConnectedNodes() throws IOException {
        String directoryNodesAvailable;
        String a = "nodes\n";
        out.write(a.getBytes());
        out.flush();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);

        while (true) {
            directoryNodesAvailable = scan.nextLine();
            addExistingNodes(directoryNodesAvailable);
            //System.out.println("Eco: " + directoryNodesAvailable);
            if (directoryNodesAvailable.equals("end")) {
                out.flush();
                printNodes();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void addExistingNodes(String sta) throws IOException {
        if (sta.equals("end")) return;
        if (!(nodess.contains(sta))) {
            nodess.add(sta);
            nodes.add(new Nodes(nodess.get(nodess.size() - 1)));
        }
        return;
    }

    public static List<Nodes> getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }

    public void printNodes() {
        System.out.println("Checking for available nodes: \n");
        nodes.forEach((z) -> System.out.println(z.getNode()));
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return socket;
    }

    public static int getHostIP() {
        return hostIP;
    }

    public InetAddress getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer. Don't change the question

Answer (score 0):

For all of those that need help in the future:

Sender side:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", hostPort);
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
ByteBlockRequest bbr = new ByteBlockRequest(getStoredData());
objectOutputStream.writeObject(bbr.blocksToSend(j));
```

Receiver side:

```
Socket = StorageNode.getServerSocket().accept();
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
byte[] bit = (byte[]) ois.readObject();
```

In my case, I needed to use byte[], so I had to do a few additional functions in the back, to change Cloudbyte[] into byte[]. Once I did that, I was able to send the data using, ObjectInput/ObjectOutput.